# Object Detection software

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, object-detection, matlab-cvst

I want to create a Movement Detection software obtaining input video through Live Stream Camera. This software will have to do the following:

1- When there's movement detected on it, it draws a rectangle around the area that has movement. -For drawing the rectangle, I thought using vision.CascadeObjectDetector, since there's an example that they use to make Face Recognition, but the problem is that I don't know if the CascadeObjectDetector works with the code that I made (videoinput). Should it be done with imaqVideoDevice?-

2- Register how many times there were movement on the screen throughout constant time, and return how many movements there were within a minute. Like performing a count of movements per minute. -As you can see in the codes, I used the tic-toc function to make the counter and the "cont" variable to count movements registered. I'd like to know, what do I need to do in order to finish the counter...-

Although I'm kinda new to Matlab, I know that it's library is full of potential and I'm willing to learn more about it.
Here's my code. You guys might want to ignore the commented parts because it is in Brazilian Portuguese.

Thanks in advance.

---

I managed the rebuild my code for `vision.ForegroundDetector` but now i'm having a issue...I don't know how to reproduce its results at the `subplot(1,2,1); imshow(FrameRGB); title('Imagem Recebida')` the only thing I know is that I don't use `imshow`...

```
%O botão Fechar, deve finalizar o código e parar a câmera
uicontrol('String', 'Fechar',...
          'Callback', 'stop(camera)',...
          'Callback', 'close');
camera = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_320x240');

Detect = vision.ForegroundDetector(...
       'NumTrainingFrames', 100, ... % 5 because of short video
       'InitialVariance', 30*30); % initial standard deviation of 30
hblob = vision.BlobAnalysis(...
       'CentroidOutputPort', false, 'AreaOutputPort', false, ...
       'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
       'MinimumBlobAreaSource', 'Property', 'MinimumBlobArea', 250);
hsi = vision.ShapeInserter('BorderColor','White');

set(camera,'TriggerRepeat', Inf);
camera.FrameGrabInterval = 1.5;

cont = 0; %cont é a variável que vai armazenar o movimento
A = 0;
timerEnd = 0;

start(camera)
timerStart = tic;
hsnk = vision.VideoPlayer();

while(camera.FramesAcquired>=0)

        FrameRGB = getsnapshot(camera);
        fgMask = step(Detect, FrameRGB);
        bbox   = step(hblob, fgMask);
        out    = step(hsi, FrameRGB, bbox); % draw bounding boxes around cars
        %drawnow;
        subplot(1,2,1); imshow(hsnk); title('Imagem Recebida')
        text(cont, timerEnd,...
        ['Contador:', num2str(cont/timerEnd)],...
        'HorizontalAlignment', 'left');


        IM = getdata(camera,2);
        IMGray = rgb2gray(IM(:,:,1:3));
        IMbw=im2bw(IMGray,0.5);
        IMneg=imadjust(IMGray,[0 1],[1 0]);

        i1=IM(:,:,:,1);
        i2=IM(:,:,:,2);
        i1=rgb2gray(i1(:,:,1:3));
        i2=rgb2gray(i2(:,:,1:3));
        m=abs(double(i1)-double(i2))/256;
        subplot(1,2,2);imshow(m);title('Detecção de Movimentos')



        if sum(sum(m))>700

            cont = cont+1;
            A = mod(cont,0);
        end

        timerEnd = toc(timerStart);
        fprintf('Em %d minutos e %f segundos, obteve-se %14.0f movimentos  \n', floor(timerEnd/60), rem(timerEnd,60), A);

end

stop(camera)
```

---

```
%O botão Fechar, deve finalizar o código e parar a câmera
uicontrol('String', 'Fechar',...
          'Callback', 'stop(camera)',...
          'Callback', 'close');
camera = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_320x240');

Detect = vision.ForegroundDetector(...
       'NumTrainingFrames', 10, ... % 5 because of short video
       'InitialVariance', 4.5*4.5); % initial standard deviation of 30

hblob = vision.BlobAnalysis(...
       'CentroidOutputPort', false, 'AreaOutputPort', false, ...
       'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
       'MinimumBlobAreaSource', 'Property', 'MinimumBlobArea', 250);
hsi = vision.ShapeInserter('BorderColor','White');

set(camera,'TriggerRepeat', Inf);
camera.FrameGrabInterval = 1.5;

cont = 0; %cont é a variável que vai armazenar o movimento
A = 0;


start(camera)
timerStart = tic;
% hsnk = vision.VideoPlayer();


while(camera.FramesAcquired>=0)

        FrameRGB = getsnapshot(camera);
        fgMask = step(Detect, FrameRGB);
        bbox   = step(hblob, fgMask);
        out    = step(hsi, FrameRGB, bbox); % draw bounding boxes around cars
        subplot(1,2,1);imshow(out);title('Imagem x')


        IM = getdata(camera,2);
        IMGray = rgb2gray(IM(:,:,1:3));
        IMbw=im2bw(IMGray,0.5);
        IMneg=imadjust(IMGray,[0 1],[1 0]);

        i1=IM(:,:,:,1);
        i2=IM(:,:,:,2);
        i1=rgb2gray(i1(:,:,1:3));
        i2=rgb2gray(i2(:,:,1:3));
        m=abs(double(i1)-double(i2))/256;
        subplot(1,2,2);imshow(m);title('Detecção de Movimentos')



        if sum(sum(m))>700

            cont = cont+1;
            A = mod(cont,0); 
        end

         if toc(timerStart) == 15.0000
            plot(A, timerEnd, 'c');
            cont = 0;      
            A = 0;
        end 

        timerEnd = toc(timerStart);
        fprintf('Em %f segundos, obteve-se %14.0f movimentos  \n',rem(timerEnd,60), A);
        %fprintf('Em %d minutos e %f segundos, obteve-se %14.0f movimentos  \n', floor(timerEnd/60), rem(timerEnd,60), A);

end


stop(camera)
```

The only problem left is the counter, which I tried to build through this line:

```
 if timerEnd == 15.0000
                plot(A, timerEnd, 'c');
                cont = 0;      
                A = 0;
            end
```

Is there anything wrong with it or is it simply the place where is located that is not making it work properly?
Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

`vision.CascadeObjectDetector` is for detecting particular object categories, such as faces, eye, noses, etc.  For motion detection you should use `vision.ForegroundDetector`, which will give you a binary mask labeling pixels as background (stationary) or foreground (moving). However, this will only work if your camera does not move.

See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) for more details.

See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-display-in-a-custom-user-interface.html) for how to put vision.VideoPlayer inside a custom UI.

Comment: Actually the project is for a static camera. I'll give it a try!

Comment: I have added a link to an example. Good luck!

Comment: So, I tried replacing vision.CascadeObjectDetector with vision.ForegroundDetector. I rebuild the entire code based on ForegroundDetector's set. Now I want to know, how do I call the image with the ForegroundDetector acting, but without using the VideoPlayer. Or if it's possible to show the content from subplot(1,2,2);imshow(m);title('Detecção de Movimentos') inside the VideoPlayer...

Comment: You can show any images in the video player, as long as they all have the same size and data type.  Or you can show the mask created by the foreground detector in imshow. I will also add a link to an example of how to use the video player in a custom axes.

Comment: I managed to put it inside my other figure, the one that is created with "subplot", but instead of using "vision.VideoPlayer", I simply used the "videoinput."
Now I'm trying to implement the counter and I have no idea why it doesn't activate during the process. I'll be updating in my question.